# Do individual databases have UUIDs in CouchDB 2?

Tags: couchdb, couchdb-2.0

I'm looking to incrementally copy data from a CouchDB to another database without copying my own bookkeeping document into the source database. Normally the replication target writes a the 'story so far' document to the source database to avoid replicating from 0 the next time around.

Is there a way to tell whether the source database is the same, perhaps by checking a per-database UUID, without writing my own target identifier to the source database? I've noticed that in CouchDB 2.0 the database itself no longer advertises a uuid on /.

Comment: Are you asking about DBs, or nodes?  The Couch 1.x uuid on / was per-node, not per DB.  The closest I'm aware of in 2.x is the node name.

Comment: It would be nice if it was per-db, to catch a deleted/remade database. How does one read the node name?